# Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n=\int f$.

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-integral, self-learning

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of non-negative Lebesgue measurable functions such that $f_n$ converges to $f$ and $f_n\leq f\ \forall n\in \mathbb{Z^+}$. It is needed to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n=\int f$. The following is my solution.

By Fatou's lemma $\int f=\int (\liminf f_n)\leq \liminf\int f_n$. Since $f_n\leq f\ \forall n\in \mathbb{Z^+}$, $\int f_n\leq\int f$. Therefore $\limsup\int f_n\leq \int f$. Therefore $\limsup\int f_n\leq \int f\leq \liminf\int f_n$. Hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n=\int f$.

Could someone tell me if my proof is correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct! Depending on the level of detail you want to include you might want to consider adding a sentence on why we can deduce that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int f_n$ exists from the fact that $\limsup \int f_n \leq \liminf \int f_n$.

For future reference, the result you have proved is called *Lebesgue's Monotone Convergence Theorem*. It is an interesting fact that one can prove the other implication as well, that is, one can derive Fatou's Lemma assuming Lebesgue's Monotone Convergence Theorem. So, if you can write down a proof of LMCT without invoking Fatou's Lemma, then you will have shown that these two results are equivalent to each other. You can take a look at Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis* for such a proof of LMCT.